# Record desktop at 1080p60 in high quality

Tags: codec, screen-casting, h.264

I am looking to record my desktop in high quality (not nearly as lossy as H.264).  I have tried OBS @ 200mbps and nVidia Shadowplay @ 50mbps and the text on my desktop is still noticibly blurry when i view the video I just recorded at the native resolution it was recorded at.  OBS is a little bit better than nVidia.

Answer (score 3):

Try lossless encoding with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)

First, with YUV444P

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -crf 0 -pix_fmt yuv444p -preset ultrafast yuv-cap.mp4
```

If not clear enough,

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -c:v libx264rgb -crf 0 -pix_fmt bgra -preset ultrafast rgb-cap.mp4
```

These will likely not be compatible with most video editors, but if the result is satisfactory, then you can transcode at leisure to a compatible codec like PNG in MOV..etc

You can add `-draw_mouse 0` before `-i desktop` to skip recording the cursor.

Comment: How would I get this up to 60fps?

Comment: Command edited.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to only capture one monitor? (i have two 1080p side-by side)

Comment: Yeah, two ways. Switch off one of them :) --or-- add `-offset_x 1920 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080` before `-i desktop` if you want to capture the 2nd monitor which is the right half of your desktop.

Comment: I've had a little time to test this out finally.  gdigrab seems to be fairly horrible at capturing high framerate desktop recording.

Comment: What I've been using: ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i desktop -c:v qtrle d:\output-test2.mov

Comment: Depends on your system's horsepower. I've multiple comps and the one I'm typing on, it struggles to do 30 smoothly, but it has a (now) low-end GPU. On another one, it does 30 smoothly, but I haven't tried higher rates. Skip the encoding i.e. use `-c:v rawvideo` and see if that helps.